# Error haciendo python3 manage.py migrate

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

Estoy experimentando diversos problemas a la hora de hacer python3 manage.py migrate. Y no sé como solucionar el problema. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

A continuación adjunto mi models.py:

```
class Responsable(models.Model):
    id_responsable = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombreapellidos = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    correo = models.EmailField()

class Proveedor(models.Model):
    id_proveedor = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    correo = models.EmailField()

class CorreoElectronico(models.Model):
    id_correo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    remitente = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    asunto = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cuerpo = models.TextField()
    attachments = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_factura = models.ForeignKey('Factura', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Estados(models.Model):
    id_estado = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Factura(models.Model):
    id_factura = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_correo = models.ForeignKey('CorreoElectronico', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    id_proveedor = models.ForeignKey('Proveedor', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    fecha_factura_recibida = models.DateField(default=dt.date.today)
    importe = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.00)])
    id_estado = models.ForeignKey('Estados', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

A continuación muestro el error que me da cuando ejecuto el comando:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 289, in ensure_connection
>     self.connect()   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 270, in connect
>     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
> line 275, in get_new_connection
>     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py",
> line 122, in connect
>     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "django_app_db_dev" to address: Name or service not known
> 
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/OneDrive/Escritorio/myproject/manage.py", line
> 22, in <module>
>     main()   File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/OneDrive/Escritorio/myproject/manage.py", line
> 18, in main
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 442, in execute_from_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 436, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 412, in run_from_argv
>     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 458, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 106, in wrapper
>     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
> line 117, in handle
>     executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)   File
> "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 18, in __init__
>     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
> line 58, in __init__
>     self.build_graph()   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
> line 235, in build_graph
>     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
> line 81, in applied_migrations
>     if self.has_table():   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
> line 57, in has_table
>     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 330, in cursor
>     return self._cursor()   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 306, in _cursor
>     self.ensure_connection()   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 288, in ensure_connection
>     with self.wrap_database_errors:   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> line 91, in __exit__
>     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 289, in ensure_connection
>     self.connect()   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 270, in connect
>     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
> line 275, in get_new_connection
>     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py",
> line 122, in connect
>     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "django_app_db_dev" to address: Name or service not known
```

A continuación adjunto la configuración de mi settings.py:

```
NAME = "django"
USER = "django" 
PASSWORD = "django" 
HOST = "django_app_db_dev"
PORT = 5432

DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': NAME,
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT,
    }
}
```

Comment: y como tienes la conexion con la base de datos en settings.py? yo creo que si no te ejecuta el comando python manage.py migrate es que tienes problemas al conectarte con la base de datos.

Comment: Podría ayudar que incluyas la configuración del proyecto.

Comment: modifico el post para añadir el settings.py

Comment: El host `django_app_db_dev` no existe. Tiene que apuntar al host (la IP, el dominio, algo) donde está la BD postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

Primero todo debe ir en comillas simples, segundo si tiene instalado el PostgreSQL en tu maquina debería cambiar el host y colocar localhost. Aquí te dejo un link de como debería ser la configuración de la conexión con PostgreSQL. https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1318-django-v2/4759-como-conectar-django-con-una-base-de-datos-en-postgresql/

```
    NAME = 'django'
    USER = 'django' 
    PASSWORD = 'django' 
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = '5432'

DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': NAME,
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT,
    }
}
```